# VB.NET - How to save info on database in this case

Tags: database, vb.net, textbox, radio-button, picturebox

I'm building a program that using a service based database.

My first problem:
I want that when somebody clicks on one of the colors it will store a `String` in the database like "color_red"

Second problem:
I want that each radio button will store a different integer

Database Schema:

[image: Database Schema]

Relevant code:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1.Table)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TableDataGridView_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub TableBindingNavigator_RefreshItems(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TableBindingNavigator.RefreshItems

    End Sub

    Private Sub Nb_typeRadioButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Nb_typeRadioButton.CheckedChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        PictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox4.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox5.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click

        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        PictureBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox4.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox5.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click

        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        PictureBox4.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox5.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox4.Click

        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox4.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        PictureBox5.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click

        PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox4.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        PictureBox5.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            Me.Validate()
            Me.TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Database1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Try
            Dim db As New Database1TableAdapters.TableTableAdapter
            Dim dbimg As String = db.GetData.Rows(0).Item(1)
            PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(dbimg)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you try to write any code and show us your progress?

Comment: The problem is your not showing any attempt to do this on your part.

Comment: a pic of my database:
http://srv1.jpg.co.il/4/54a859e4bf576.jpg

I tired many things but nothing could be useful to understand.

Comment: So show your attempt, maybe it just need a slight adjustment.

Comment: This is my code: http://pastebin.com/SGUrnqBN
a picture of the form is here: http://srv1.jpg.co.il/2/54a860fb6b8e5.bmp

My main problem is that I don't know how to translate a picture click to a value for the database and same with the radio button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will update my answer as soon as you provide more quality information.
For now here is what I understood you want to do:

In `Button.Click` event you should write:

```
If Me.Radiobutton1.Checked = True than
            Value = 1 '' For Example
        Else
            Value = 2 '' For Example
        End If
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
        If Me.Radiobutton1.Checked = True than
            Value = 1
        ElseIf Me.Radiobutton2.Checked = True than
            Value = 2
        End if
```

This is about giving values according to checked `RadioButton`.

And about marked `PictureBox` I would just add to `Button.Click` event:

```
        If Me.PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D Then
            StringValue = 1
        ElseIf Me.PictureBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D Then
            StringValue = 2
        ElseIf Me.PictureBox3.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D Then
            StringValue = 3
        ElseIf Me.PictureBox4.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D Then
            StringValue = 4
        ElseIf Me.PictureBox5.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D Then
            StringValue = 5
        End If
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i asked for but now my question is how can I store this information on the database?

Comment: I am sorry but that is completely different question. You should open a new question for that. But I recommend you to check out answers on Stack since you will find an answer 100%. Also, if my question helped you solve your problem please up vote it and check it as answer. Best regards, Hoh